# Activity won't recognize custom theme

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop, android-xml

I've tried 3 different places (manifest, onCreate & XML) to get custom theme for a single activity but it just won't work? It fails in genymotion & on a device as well. The manifest code

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomepageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_homepage"
        android:theme="@style/SecondTheme">
</activity>
```

this is onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.SecondTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
```

this is the XML

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:theme="@style/SecondTheme"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

this is styles v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="SecondTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here -->

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>

</style>
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

As per your code the theme is only ment to v21. move the theme file to value folder

Comment: tried that prior to moving it to v21 but makes no difference, originally I used values/styles.xml

Comment: I said move from v21 to value folder.